# Notepad++ stylers.model: Edit to change cursor color to white to hide it / stop it from blinking?

Tags: notepad++, text-cursor

In notepad++, I sometimes get annoyed with the blinking of the insertion point. I couldn't find any info on how to hide it. Changing the cursor behavior in Windows' accessibility options only affects Word.

I saw a post mentioning how you can edit the "stylers.model" file:

"Yes, you can change the cursor color, edit the stylers.xml.
However there is no option to change the type that it is".

Does anyone know what you edit in the stylers.model file to get the blinker to be white?

I'm assuming that that would hide it.

Answer (score 14):

To stop it blinking, you can do this via the menu.

Settings -> Preferences, then on the "Edit Components" tab, slide the "Blink rate" slider all the way to the "S" (Slow) end.  Then it won't blink at all.

I don't know how to change the cursor colour in the ".model" file, but again there is a menu option:

Settings -> Style Configurator.

Then in the "Language" list, select "Global Styles".  The "Style" list should then have a "Caret colour" entry.  Set that to white / whatever you want.

I'm using v5.3.1, so things may be slightly different in the current version (5.5.1).

--

Alternatively, just noticed the "Width" option on that Settings -> Preferences -> Edit Components tab.  Set that to zero, and there won't be a cursor at all. No need to change colours, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer otherchirps!
Caret! I forgot about that. Insertion point, cursor, blinking vertical line.. there's too many names.
I was about to decide between changing the color to either white or gray to have it blend in.
However, you can just go to Settings -> Preferences and set the Width of the Caret to 0.
That will hide it.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Click

```
Settings -> Preferences -> Editing -> "Caret Settings"
```

Adjust the width(1) and blink rate fast to slow.

Answer (score 5):

most of the programmers face this problem just press 'insert' button that solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

you can set both (caret width and blink rate, in preferences window)

> Settings -> Preferences
>   [image]